# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, php-7.3

I have a model I plan to save the input to two different tables but I have an error

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Argument 1
>   passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of
>   the type array, object given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php
>   on line 23

the first table is `Transaction_in` and the second is `Transaction_in_detail`. I planned to use `idTransaction_in` as a connector between 2 tables and that column is not a primaryKey (is it a good practice)? I can save the input to `Transcation_in` table but still failed to save the input to the 2nd table and I don't know how to make the `idTransaction_in` column as a connector.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'supplier_name' => 'required',
        'transaction_in_date' => 'required|before_or_equal:today',
        'device_type_name' => 'required',
        'device_brand_name' => 'required',
        'device_spec' => 'required|max:255',
        'price' => 'required',
        'amount' => 'required',
        'total_price' => 'required',
        'keterangan' => 'Nullable',

        ]);


    $transaction_in = new Transaction_in();
    $transaction_in->idTransaction_in = "0";
    $transaction_in->Supplier_id = $request->input('supplier_name');
    $transaction_in->tanggal_transaksi = $request->input('transaction_in_date');
    $transaction_in->save();
    $transaction_in->update(['idTransaction_in' => sprintf('TIN-%04d', $transaction_in->id)]);

    $lastid=Transaction_in::create($transaction_in)->idTransaction_in;
    if(count($request->device_type_name)>0){
        foreach ($request->device_type_name as $item => $v) {
            $data2=array(
                'Transaction_in_id' => $lastid,
                'DeviceType_id' => $request->device_type_name[$item],
                'DeviceBrand_id' => $request->device_brand_name[$item],
                'spek_device' => $request->device_spec[$item],
                'harga_device' => $request->price[$item],
                'jumlah_device' => $request->amount[$item],
                'total_harga_device' => $request->total_price[$item]
            );
            Transaction_in_detail::insert($data2);
        }
    }

    return redirect('/transactionsin')->with('success', 'Transaction success');
}
```

The `DeviceType_id` and `Devicebrand_id` are foreign key.

Comment: Please post your migration table and model. Atleast migration & model for `Transaction_in` and `Transaction_in_detail`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you have problem in this line

```php
$lastid=Transaction_in::create($transaction_in)->idTransaction_in;
```

`$transaction_in` is object and `create` method requires `array` to be passed in.

If everything else is correct this should work:

```php
$lastid=Transaction_in::create($transaction_in->toArray())->idTransaction_in;
```

Comment: Hi, your answer does remove the error but i getting a new error ` SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '51' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `transaction_ins` (`idTransaction_in`, `Supplier_id`, `tanggal_transaksi`, `updated_at`, `created_at`, `id`) values (TIN-0051, 1, 2019-10-08, 2019-10-28 18:06:31, 2019-10-28 18:06:31, 51)) `

Comment: Because two id is inserted twice. Try doing this instead of `toArray`.  `$transaction_in->pull('id')->toArray()`

Comment: you mean like this `$lastid = Transaction_in::create($transaction_in->pull(id))->toArray();`, its working but give me another error " Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) "

Comment: You forget to wrap `id` in single quotes. copy my exact code

Comment: I'm sorry I bother one more time but i have this `Call to undefined method App\Transaction_in::pull() `

Comment: Ok. Then place this code before `$lastid = ...` line `unset($transaction_in->id)` and use `toArray()` without `pull` method

Answer (score 0):

You have already `save` the data, but you use `create` also. It will create duplicate records in your DB.

I will give you a solution:

```php
$transactionIn = Transaction_in::create([
    'idTransaction_id' => '0',
    'supplier_id' => $request->input('supplier_name') // why supplier name assigned supplier_id?
    'tanggal_transaksi' => $request->input('transaction_in_date'),
]);

$transactionIn = tap($transaction_in)->update([
    'idTransaction_in' => sprintf('TIN-%04d', $transactionIn->id)
]);

$lastId = $transactionIn->idTransaction_in;
```

Comment: your answer give me another error ` SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'TIN-0082' for column `blog`.`transaction_in_details`.`Transaction_in_id` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `transaction_in_details` (`Transaction_in_id`, `DeviceType_id`, `DeviceBrand_id`, `spek_device`, `harga_device`, `jumlah_device`, `total_harga_device`) values (TIN-0082, 2, 1, 234, 234, 234444, 54859896)) `

Comment: No, It's not. It's an error from your other code. I only answer your question, not fix all your code.

Comment: I think you need to be more clear what do you want to ask.